# LINQ SqlMethods.Like (and .Contains) fails

Tags: vb.net, linq, filter, contains

I have a class called `Person` which has the properties `FirstName`, `LastName` and `MiddleName` and I have a form-wide SortedDictionary(Of Integer, Person)  called `oPeople`.

On `Form_Load`, I call a method that loads a list of 65 people. Right now this is hard-coded but eventually I'll be grabbing it from a database.

Once the form is loaded, I have a `TextBox` called `txtSearchForName` for the user to enter a search term and have the system look through `oPeople` filtering on `LastName` for a full or partial match (case insensitive).

Eventually I would like to be able to search for comparisons between FirstName, LastName and MiddleName (if there is one).

At this point all I want to do is loop through the results of the LINQ query and output them to the console window.

Here's the `Person` class:

```
Public Class Person

    Private _fnm As String = String.Empty
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _fnm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _fnm = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _lnm As String = String.Empty
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return _lnm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _lnm = value.Trim
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _mnm As String = String.Empty
    Public Property MiddleName() As String
        Get
            Return _mnm
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _mnm = value.Trim
        End Set
     End Property

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal firstName As String,
                   ByVal lastName As String,
                   Optional ByVal middleName As String = "")

        _fnm = firstName
        _lnm = lastName
        _mnm = middleName

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the method I'm using to add people. I'm adding 65 people but have cut the code down:

```
Private Sub FillPeopleDictionary()

    Try

        If oPeople.Count > 0 Then oPeople.Clear()

        Dim oNewPerson As Person = Nothing

        oNewPerson = New Person("Scarlett", "Johansson")
        oPeople.Add(1, oNewPerson)

        oNewPerson = New Person("Amy", "Adams")
        oPeople.Add(2, oNewPerson)

        oNewPerson = New Person("Jessica", "Biel")
        oPeople.Add(3, oNewPerson)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error [FillPeopleDictionary]", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    End Try

End Sub
```

This is my LINQ statement followed by the output to console which is called when the user clicks a button:

```
Dim sSearchTerm As String = txtSearchForName.Text.Trim.ToLower

Dim queryResults = From person In oPeople
'Where SqlMethods.Like(person.Value.LastName.ToLower, "%" & sSearchTerm & "%")
'Where person.Value.LastName.ToLower.Contains("%" & sSearchTerm & "%")

Console.WriteLine("search term: " & sSearchTerm &
                  Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine &
                  "queryResults.Count: " & queryResults.Count.ToString &
                  Environment.NewLine)

For Each result In queryResults

   If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Value.MiddleName) Then

      Console.WriteLine(result.Key.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0") & ": " & result.Value.FirstName & " " & result.Value.MiddleName & " " & result.Value.LastName)

   Else

      Console.WriteLine(result.Key.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0") & ": " & result.Value.FirstName & " " & result.Value.LastName)

   End If

Next
```

The LINQ statement works as it stands, with no conditions, so it loops through and correctly lists all of the people in the `oPeople` collection.

There are two `Where` clauses commented out below the initial `queryResults` statement. Those are the two ways I was trying to filter. One approach was to use `.Contains` and the other was to use `.Like` however neither works.

If the user was to type "mar", I would hope to get back a list of 6 people from the list of 65(case insensitive):

> Meghan Markle
>   Margo Robbie
>   Kate Mara
>   Mary Elizabeth Winstead
>   Marian Rivera
>   Amy Smart

Now of course that is searching on `FirstName` and `LastName`. Right now I am just trying to get `LastName` to work. With only the `LastName` the list would only be:

> Meghan Markle
>   Kate Mara
>   Amy Smart

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Or should I scrap the idea of using LINQ with a SortedDictionary?

Comment: Why are you using `SqlMethods` on a common ordinary NET collection?  Also, thanks for posting 130 *double spaced* lines showing how you added 60 some people.  Most of us would get the idea after 2 or 3. see  [MCVE]

Comment: Plutonix - I am using SQLMethods only because I am simply trying to understand how LINQ works. This is my first attempt at using it so I thought it best to start with something I'm somewhat comfortable with (SortedDictionaries). Jinx88909 showed me that a List(Of T) is a better approach.

Comment: `SqlMethods` is for Linq to SQL.  you dont need it to learn about linq or extension methods as in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Person` class to include a `PersonId` and pass that through like `oNewPerson = New Person(1, "Scarlett", "Johansson")`.

Change the oPeople to be a `List(Of Person`) so when adding it would look like this `oPeople.Add(oNewPerson)`.

Your LINQ statement would then look like this:

```
Dim queryResults = From person In oPeople
                   Where person.FirstName.ToLower Like "*" & sSearchTerm & "*" Or
                         person.LastName.ToLower Like "*" & sSearchTerm & "*"
```

You would also want to change the rest as no longer using a dictionary:

```
For Each result In queryResults

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.MiddleName) Then

        Console.WriteLine(result.PersonId.ToString.PadLeft(2, CChar("0")) & ": " & result.FirstName & " " & result.MiddleName & " " & result.LastName)

    Else

        Console.WriteLine(result.PersonId.ToString.PadLeft(2, CChar("0")) & ": " & result.FirstName & " " & result.LastName)

    End If

Next
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This fixed it. As I am trying to learn more about LINQ I do have a question. Does LINQ not work with sorted dictionaries? I am not against using Lists(Of T) I am just curious. Thank you for taking the time to fully explain what was being changed and providing the code. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it would still work however felt it would be beneficial to pop the PersonId in the class rather than have a dictionary then you can reference the property rather than .Key for the Id or .Value.FirstName. For me it's just a little cleaner. Glad it fixed the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd `Where` clause attempt is close, except the `Contains` function there is [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) which does not use the `%` wildcard characters that SQL uses, so you need:

```
Dim queryResults =
    From person In oPeople
    Where person.Value.LastName.ToLower.Contains(sSearchTerm)
```

You can easily add a check for `FirstName` with `OrElse person.Value.FirstName.ToLower.Contains(sSearchTerm)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went with Jinx88909's response from above. I did incorporate your suggestion of the OrElse. Worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Linq query to be as follows:

```
Dim queryResults = From p In oPeople
                               Where p.Value.FirstName.ToLower.Contains(sSearchTerm) Or p.Value.LastName.ToLower.Contains(sSearchTerm)
```

Comment: I tried this but it still gave me no results. I'm not sure what I did wrong. I ended up going with Jinx88909's response from above. Thank you for taking the time. It is very much appreciated.